# Not allowing hyphenation of urls in references

Tags: hyphenation, urls

Is there a way to globally turn off hyphenation of links in bibliography?
Current state doesn't please me:

[image: current state]

Minmal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\begin{document}

\cite{mchinen}

\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{general}
\end{document}
```

and here is the general.bib entry:

```
@url{mchinen,
Author = {Chinen, Michael},
Date-Added = {2013-05-01 10:12:23 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2013-05-01 10:34:20 +0000},
Lastchecked = {March 23, 2013},
Title = {{M}ichael {C}hinen},
Url = {http://michaelchinen.com},
Urldate = {March 23, 2013},
Year = {2013},
Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://michaelchinen.com}}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @DownVoters: What’s the problem?

Comment: I have updated the answer with MWE.

Comment: It's a "balancing" problem: if you don't break the URL, the line will be way underfull.

Comment: I know, but I don't think it is appropriate to break URL like that, especially in the point of "http://"

Comment: a way to avoid underfull/stretched lines in the bibliography (and thus avoid most breaks in urls) is to set it ragged right.  but if a url is longer than the text width, you may have no alternative to breaking (*not* hyphenating) it to avoid it getting cut off as it runs off the edge of the paper.

Comment: Please do not use swearwords in your posts and images, even if they are meant as a joke. Please update your image accordantly.

Comment: Please avoid "Edit" and "Update" markers. They are breaking the flow. Simply update your post or edit the new material into the existing one. Other users will be able to clearly see that it got changed and can see the differences in the history.

Comment: @Papiro The OP uses `apacite`, but the specific problem is not related to it (see also the accepted answer). Therefore, I removed the [tag:apa-style] tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The break points set by package `url` can be configured by setting `\UrlBreakPenalty` and `\UrlBigBreakPenalty`. A value of 10000 prevents the hyphenation:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{libertine}

\mathchardef\UrlBreakPenalty=10000
\mathchardef\UrlBigBreakPenalty=10000

\begin{document}

\cite{mchinen}

\begingroup
  \raggedright
  \bibliographystyle{apacite}
  \bibliography{general}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Also the example uses `\raggedright` to avoid overstretched lines. You can also consider a slightly smaller value `9999` to make it possible to break URLs that do not fit in one line.

> [image: Result]